# mongoose schema is broken into several files, how to require?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

doing mongoose db in nodejs.
i got an error: "schema is not defined".

in my model i have 2 files for different schemas: user and product, they look smth like:

```
'use strict';
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");

var UsersSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  email: String,
  telephone: Number,
  createdAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
  updatedAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});


var userModel = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
module.exports.userModel = userModel;
```

I have nothing in routes, and in app.js, I've got:

```
var users = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
var products = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);
```

Previously I tried:

```
 var users = require('../models/userSchema');
 var products= require('../models/productSchema');
```

any advise? thanks

Comment: I think this is referring to the code in `new Schema`. After you import mongoose, do `const Schema = mongoose.Schema` (or `var` if desired). If using ES6 imports you could also do `import mongoose, {Schema} from 'mongoose'`

Comment: Any feedback on the given answers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get rid of requiring mongoose models in your code by putting them in app.

Add index.js file in the folder (let's say 'models') where user.js and product.js are placed:

```
var fs                = require('fs');
var path              = require('path');
module.exports = function(app) {
    app.models = app.models || {};
    fs.readdirSync(__dirname).forEach(function(file) {
        if (file !== "index.js" && path.extname(file) === '.js'){
            var model = require(path.join(__dirname,file))(app);
            app.models[model.modelName] = model;

        }
    });
};
```

Change user.js (and similarly product.js) file to

```
'use strict';
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
module.exports = function(){
    var UsersSchema = new Schema({
        name: String,
        email: String,
        telephone: Number,
        createdAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
        updatedAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
    });
    return mongoose.model("User", UsersSchema); //the name "User" here will be stored as key in app.models and its value will be the model itself
};
```

And in app.js  insert a line

```
 require("./app/models")(app) //pass app to the index.js, which will add models to it
```

Now you can use app.models.User and app.models.Product across the application.

Comment: can you please elaborate on require("./app/models")(app)? Thank you.

Comment: ok, i figured it out, however now, when I add any other db js file by your example, I am not seeing that collection in my db.

Answer (score 2):

To resolve the "schema is not defined" issue, import the Mongoose schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
```

For the exports, I would suggest the following. No reason to nest this additionally, when you're defining one model per file:

```
var userModel = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
module.exports = userModel;
```

Then you can require the model in other files as shown in your post, e.g.:

```
var users = require('../models/userSchema');
```